# Having problems with reading resourcefile in .jar

Tags: java, classpath

I have problems with reading of a resourcefile which is within my jar.

This is the directory structure:

src/main/java

src/main/resources

I am working with IntelliJ and have set the source folder in the project structure to "src".
I always get a NullPointerException, because the needed file can not be found.
How can I access a file in the resources directory from a class somewhere in the java directory? I can't get it working right now...

I have already searched a lot on the internet (and also on stackoverlow), but none of those answers could solve my problem.

Right now I am using the Main.class which is directly in the directory src/main/java/.
I am trying to get the resourcefile with Main.class.getResource("resources/config.properties").

Thank you very much for your responses!

F_Schmidt

Comment: It may be a good idea to share the code you're using to read the file which I guess is located under src/main/resources.

Comment: Yep. I know that. But how can I search in the resources directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntelliJ you shouldn't mark the src Directory as Sources. Instead mark (in File/ Project Structure... / Sources )

- src/main/java as Sources Root
- src/main/resources as Resources Root

it should be something like

[image]